# Can I skip writing flushAutomatically=true in Modifying annotation?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

For example, instead of

```
@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true)
```

Only

```
@Modifying
```

I do understand that the main point of it - to flush all cache to DB before querying,
But after we write @Query isn't JPQL query already processed by JPA? And JPA has default Flushmode = AUTO, so it should flush data to db anyway.

Am I thinking right? If yes, can I skip this annotation?

P.S. I haven't found anything on stackoverflow that is answering that question, so it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As it's discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1167):

> `@Modifying` annotation has `clearAutomatically` attribute which defines whether it should clear the underlying persistence context after executing the modifying query.
>
> ...
>
> When executing modifying queries with this attribute activated, it drops all non-flushed changes still pending in the `EntityManager`.
>
> ...
>
> Is it possible to add a new attribute to `@Modifying` annotation called `flushAutomatically` to automatically flush all non-persisted changes to the underlying context before executing the modifying query?

and further

> JPA’s `AUTO` `FlushModeType` and Hibernate: if the current executed query is not going to hit the pending SQL INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements then the flush is not strictly required.
>
> As stated in the reference documentation, the `AUTO` flush strategy may sometimes synchronize the current persistence context prior to a query execution.
>
> The `clearAutomatically` property drops all the pending changes in the EntityManager that are not related to the current update query (cause they are not automatically flushed).
>
> That's why I'm asking for a new property to force the `EntityManager` to flush changes.

So, this property have sense only when you use also `clearAutomatically` property: `@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)`.